# displaying date in MM/dd/yyyy format using label

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i`m new to asp.net,i`m trying to display out my date output in terms of

```
    MM/dd/yyyy
```

but it came out with

```
    MM/dd/yyyy 12:00:00 AM
```

what can i do to remove the time?
my vb.net code is like this:

```
    Dim date As String = myDataReader("date").ToString()
        lbldate.Text = date
```

Comment: try to put `CDate(myDataReader("date").ToString())`

Comment: thanks MAC
problem solved!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the format to the `.ToString` method, like this:

```
.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

It would also be a good idea to cast the `myDataReader("date")` to a `DateTime` object, like this:

```
Dim dateValue As DateTime = CType(myDataReader("date"), DateTime)
Dim date As String

If dateValue Is Not Nothing Then
   date = dateValue.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
End If
```

*Note* - If the `TryCast` fails, then `Nothing` would be the value of `dateValue`, hence the `If dateValue Is Not Nothing Then` logic is there.

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format.
i get this error when i do as your suggested answer.

Comment: @JoeCheong - Does casting the `myDataReader("date")` to a `DateTime` object return `Nothing` or a valid object? I have not worked with VB.NET in a few years and I am not sure if my casting syntax is correct.

Comment: 'TryCast' operand must be reference type, but 'Date' is a value type.
i got this error...

Comment: @JoeCheong - Does `CType(myDataReader("date"), DateTime)` work?

Comment: @JoeCheong - glad it worked for you, feel free to up-vote and/or accept the answer if it helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the format to [`ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
Dim date As String = myDataReader("date").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Comment: Input string was not in a correct format.
i get this error ><

Comment: @JoeCheong make sure that `myDataReader("date")` returns a valid DateTime.

Comment: the date is a data which pull from database

Comment: Does the database use a datetime column? It should.